# Angular 2 shared element router Transition animation

Tags: angular, animation, transition, shared-element-transition

I would like to create a transition between routes where some elements are shared but am unsure of what the best way to go about this in angular 2+ (currently on 5) is.

Ive attached a mockup animation and some basic requirements

- plant.com/plants shows a list of plant thumbnails in a grid
- plant.com/plant/3 shows a detail view of plant id 3, you should be able to navigate straight to this view. navigating to/from this page should transition smoothly between detail and thumbnail views.
- closing this view should return the thumbnail to its place in the grid

any points in the right direction would be appreciated, thank you

[image: router transition mockup]

Comment: Did you see [the tutorial where you can animate your routes](https://angular.io/guide/router#adding-animations-to-the-routed-component) ?

Comment: thanks ill have a look.